URL Rewriting Works on Custom Domain but Not on http://localhost/ Using .htaccess in Laragon
I am developing my first ERP software in PHP.
I have a .htaccess file which redirects all the requests to my index.php which then, requires my router.php file where I do all the logic of handing endpoints.
I use Laragon on Windows 11. The routes are working as long as I use their custom url feature.
Example of what works:

myproject.test/login

Example of what isn't working:

localhost/myproject/login

.htaccess
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?path=$1 [NC,L,QSA]

index.php
<?php

require __DIR__ . '/router/router.php';

router.php
<?php

$uri = parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])['path'];

$routes = [
    '/login' => 'pages/login.php',
];

if (array_key_exists($uri, $routes)) {
    require $routes[$uri];
} else {
    http_response_code(404);
    require "pages/errors/404.php";
    return 0;
}

I suspect it's a problem with my .htaccess. I tried enabling the mod in my apache2 config files & changing the value from None to All in the apache2.conf.
Also changed the routes in the router.php but was not successful
Example Bellow
Works
Does not work

This question is similar to: How does RewriteBase work in .htaccess. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

People who need to send all requests to an index.php router script always use mod_rewrite but you don't need to struggle with all the complexity if you don't need other module features. mod_dir offers the more accessible FallbackResource directive that only does one thing, so it's hard to use wrong.
